# Extracting values in JSON text file in Python

Tags: python, json

I currently have a text file in JSON format of ip addresses with their ports, example:

```json
[
 {
   "ip": "192.0.3.202",
   "port": [
    22,
    53,
    80,
    443]
  },
{
   "ip": "192.0.3.253",
   "port": [
    179]
  }
]
```

I want to print out only the ip and on another line with ports. Expected output:

```
IP: 192.0.3.202
Port: 22,53,80,443

IP: 192.0.3.253
Port: 179
```

I have tried doing this:

```
i=0
while True:
    ip_test = open('test.txt', 'r')
    ip_line=ip_test.readlines()
    a=ip_line[i].strip("{\"ip\": ")
    print(a)
```

However my output is only stripping out the first few characters

Comment: Did you read https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html? You can also use pandas:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strip` doesn't remove a prefix; it removes any leading or trailing character that appears in the iterable argument.

But you shouldn't be trying to parse the contents manually; use `json` to parse the data and work with the resulting `dict`.

```
import json

with open('test.txt') as ip_test:
    data = json.load(ip_test)

for obj in data:
    print(f"IP: {obj['ip']}")
    print(f"Port: {','.join(obj['port'])}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just manipulating the text perhaps isn't the best way to go about this, as Python offers support for JSON in the standard libraries.

You can access the library by using `import json` and then manipulating the resulting array.

See the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module :

```
import json

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for address in json.load(f):
        print(f"ID: {address['ip']}\nPort: {', '.join(map(str, address['port']))}\n")
```

---

Output:

```
ID: 192.0.3.202
Port: 22, 53, 80, 443

ID: 192.0.3.253
Port: 179
```